# Particle size that can be driven by electrical field or magnetic field

Tags: forces, magnetic-fields, electric-fields

Does anyone know what size-range of metal particles can be driven by either electrical field or magnetic field? For example, should the size be nano-meter range or micrometer?

Comment: That depends by what you mean by driven and also how strong the fields are.

Answer (score 2):

There is almost no limit to the size of a "particle" that can be moved by a magnetic field. See for example this picture ([source](http://ducknetweb.blogspot.co.uk/2010/06/mri-accident-earlier-this-year-kills.html?_sm_au_=i1VwTD6MW2FTWZP6))

[image]

which shows an entire hospital gurney being sucked into an MRI scanner. In this case the patient was injured but survived. Not all are that lucky.

Bottom line: with a sufficiently strong (and diverging) field, a ferromagnetic "particle" can be very large, and yet be moved.